# CSS: how to vertically align objects so that increasing the font size of the label doesn't throw everything off?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, font-size

I'm having this problem where my buttons align correctly until I change the font size of the label, at which point my second set of buttons is misaligned.

Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image: After]

In the second picture, note how setting the font size of the "Sort by:" label to 2em shifts the buttons "Title," "Creator," and "Date Added" down about 10 pixels. I've tried setting `vertical-align: middle` on all the elements, but so far nothing seems to work.

Comment: Can you post your HTML? If those are all `span` elements you can just use `vertical-align: middle;` on `#sort-links`

Answer (score 0):

you can set float:left to .sort-label class 
or 
set vertical-align: top; with "line-height";

also check the display property of "pagination" class and "sort-links" id.